# Constrain a control's Parent to a particular type in Windows Forms with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I want to write a control which can only have a parent of type `Form` (or derivatives).

I guess you might liken this behaviour to the `TabControl`, or `TabPage`, where a `TabControl` cannot have children that are not of type `TabPage`, and `TabPage` cannot have a parent that is not a `TabControl`.

However my implementation differs slightly because unlike `TabControl`, I want my `Form` to accept any type of control, but my control should only ever have a parent of type `Form`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public class CustomControl : ContainerControl
{
    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
        if (!(this.Parent is Form))
        {
            this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
            throw new ArgumentException("CustomControl can only be a child of Form");
        }
    }
}
```

This causes some undesired effects in the forms designer, such as:

1. Throws an exception when trying to load the form in the designer.
2. Throws an exception when removing the control from the form.
3. The control does not resize properly.

I'd appreciate any recommendation on how to fix this, or points as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: What value do you get out of implementing this restriction?

Comment: @RyanGates, the control alter's the behaviour of a Form, and does not apply to controls that are not Forms. Also, the behavioural alterations should not be implemented at Form level, it should be a separate control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As quite often said, the simplest answers are often the best...adding an additional check to the `if` statement fixes everything! - Silly me! I should have tried this sooner!

```
public class CustomControl : ContainerControl
{
    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
        if (this.Parent != null && !(this.Parent is Form))
        {
            this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
            throw new ArgumentException("CustomControl can only be a child of Form");
        }
    }
}
```